# Within a Ruby method, should I create a proc or a method?

Tags: ruby, methods, proc

Just want to enquire what the right practice is.

My preference is to use procs, simply because I think that defining methods inside of methhods is a bit untidy and should be done only when necessary. To get around it, I simply use procs.

What is the right / better way to do it and why? (apart from the proc's ability to access the main method's variables defined before itself)

```
def meth( params_prime )

  calculations = do_something_with_whatever

  def sub_meth( params_sub )
    do_something_with_params_sub
  end

  sub_meth_params(calculations) # is this better?

  proc1 = proc{ |params_sub| do_something_with_params_sub }
  proc1.call(calculations) # or is this?

end
```

Comment: Care to shed some more light on why you would need this? Defining functions in functions is not something I would recommend. It limits reuse and generally not sure if it improves readability. A little more background could help to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what your specific use-case is, but I would definitely go for procs or lambdas. There is less overhead when defining a proc or lambda dynamically, they are passable, so if needed you could return them and they could be used outside the function.

Using "def" exposes the method as an instance method outside of the current method scope (so in the containing class, which could be `Object` in your case). This may  or may not be with you want. If you want to use an anonymous function only available in the local scope, use a lambda.

Also Proc vs Lambda: I generally prefer to use lambdas since they behave a little more "predictable", meaning: as you would expect (check passed variables, and return just returns from the lambda, proc returns from the called scope). But from your example it is hard to deduce what would apply. I think the key-difference is: lambas are ment to be passed around, and thus behave a little more sanely. If this is not your use-case, use `Proc` :) (a [write-up](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/) of the difference).

Comment: +1, but I don't think that the difference between procs and lambdas is the asker's concern. I think he is having a more basic ambiguity of organizing his code. Defining procs / lambdas inside `def`s is not a very common practice either.

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah, when you accept somone's answer, you can consider to also upvote it to boot.

Comment: He has not enough rep to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Defining methods inside methods is a feature of Ruby that may have its use. But something is telling me that you are asking a very advanced question while you are still a beginner level Rubyist. Do you know what default definee is? If not, [check this article by Yugui](http://yugui.jp/articles/846).

Procs are very important in Ruby, but newbies tend to use them instead of defining methods in appropriate objects, which is the exact smell I'm getting from your question. The normal way of doing things in OO languages of Ruby family is to define methods on objects:

```
class Foo
  def bar *params
    # do something with params
  end
end
```

Since you do not understand the meaning of defining methods inside methods, refrain from doing it for the next 6 months. Once you understand objects, you can start experimenting with this very advanced feature again.

APPENDIX:

Since you demonstrated intrest, let me show you that using `def` in `def` at the top level is a frownable-upon thing to do. Normally, when you define a method on some class without further adornment, it becomes a public instance method of that class:

```
class X
  def foo; "foo" end
end

X.instance_methods.include? :foo
#=> true
```

When you use `def` in a `def`, the definee for the inner def is going to be `X`:

```
class X
  def bar
    def baz
      "baz"
    end
    "bar"
  end
end
```

When you execute the above code, instance method #bar becomes defined on X:

```
X.instance_methods.include? :bar
#=> true
```

But #baz not yet:

```
X.instance_methods.include? :baz
#=> false
```

Only after you call `#bar` at least once does the method become defined on X:

```
X.new.bar
#=> "bar"
X.instance_methods.include? :baz
#=> true
```

And now I would like to ask you to appreciate how terrible thing just happened: An instance just modified its mother class. That's a violation. A violation of such a basic principle of OO design, that I'm not even sure it has a name. This technique is great for obfuscated coding competitions, but in production, it's taboo. Ruby gives you the freedom to break that taboo, gives you the rope to hang yourself on, but you don't do it under any kind of normal circumstances.

So what can be worse than a `def` inside a `def` in a class definition? The answer is, a `def` inside a `def` at the top level. Let me show you why. Normally, when you define methods with `def` at the top level, the default definee is `Object`, but the top level defnitions become *private* instance methods of object. This is to prevent the unintended consequence of top level `def`s, because almost all Ruby objects  inherit from `Object`. For example, if you define:

```
class Object
  def foo; "foo" end
end
```

Now all your objects will respond to foo:

```
foo        #=> "foo"
1.foo      #=> "foo"
[].foo     #=> "foo
```

When we define methods at the top level, we usually just intend to use the method at the top level, and don't want every single object to inherit it. For that reason, top level `def`s become private:

```
hello      #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `hello' for main:Object
1.hello    #=> NoMethodError: undifined method 'hello' for 1:Fixnum
```

Now we use `def` at the top level:

```
def hello; "hello" end
```

We can see that method `#hello` is has not become an instance methods of `Object`:

```
Object.instance_methods.include? :hello
#=> false
```

Mysteriously, it became its private method:

```
Object.private_instance_methods.include? :hello
#=> true
```

This way, we avoid the unintended consequence of defining `#hello` method for every single object. But the inheritance is there. The error message has changed:

```
1.hello    #=> NoMethodError: private method 'hello' called for 1:Fixnum
```

And we can forcibly call the method via `#send`:

```
1.send :hello
#=> "hello"
```

Mysteriously, at the top level, we are allowed to call this private method without `#send`:

```
hello
#=> "hello"
```

And now, what happens when you do `def` in `def` at the top level:

```
def bar
  def baz; "baz" end
  "bar"
end
```

You define a private instance method `Object#bar` in an expected way. But when you call it, alas, the top level magic no longer works and a *public* method `Object#baz` gets defined:

```
bar      #=> "bar"
```

This way, not just the top level, but every single Ruby object got polluted with your `#baz` method:

```
1.baz       #=> "baz"
Class.baz   #=> "baz"
```

This is why I told you to refrain from using this idiom until you progress from the level of unconscious incompetence to the level of conscious incompetence. I recommend you to read more about [top level methods in Ruby](http://vitobotta.com/top-level-methods-ruby/#sthash.CHlrIAUf.dpbs).

Comment: What sounds condescending to you is just me trying to take you [from stage 0 of understanding, unconscious incompetence, to stage 1, conscious incompetence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence). Also, don't use the theoretical term function when you actually mean a method, there is a subtle terminological difference between the two. A `def` inside a `def` becomes defined on the _default definee_. On the top level, default definee is Object, but `def` inside a `def` at the top level introduces an additional complication. I will edit the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Awwww @BorisStitnicky given the little information in the question and the lack of reputation I understand your answer, albeit a little condescending indeed. But your reply definitely is. Wtf? "conscious incompetence" ???

Comment: @nathanvda, when achieving competence, one in general [goes through four stages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence). At the first stage, one does not even realize that he or she has a problem of not understanding something. At the second stage, termed "conscious incometence", one realizes that there is something he or she doesn't know and needs to learn. "Conscious incompetence" here is a technical term, not an insult. It is a commendable thing to achieve.

Comment: I understand that. The condescending thing is you assume to know which stage the OP is at. While the question or profile offer very little information either way, the comment of the OP at least clarifies he is past the beginner level.

Comment: @nathanvda, maybe in other programming languages. But this question is almost like asking whether it is better to drill holes with a hammer, or with pliers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sub_func to encapsulate it from call from other methods you can use a class to group function and sub_func together and make sub_func private. Otherwise if you want to pass this function as a parameter further you can declare it as lamda.

```
def func params_prime
  sub_func = ->(params_sub){do_something_with_params}  
  sub_func.call(params_prime)
end
```